# How to get claims from OpenID Connect provider in Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am having some issues getting claims from an OpenID Connect provider with an Azure AD B2C custom policy.

My OIDC provider does not return any claims in the `id_token`, it has a separate endpoint for claims called `userInfo_endpoint` where you send a GET request with Bearer authentication and the `access_token` go get user claims in json format. I understand this is pretty standard OIDC functionality.

Most examples I see use the ClaimsEndpoint to get claims and it seems to me the claims are added to the user as part of the signin_signup user journey.

Everything up to this point works as expected, testClaim is returned from b2c as part of the id_token, but no other claims are set. I have Application Insights set up for the policy, but the endpoint `/userinfo` is never called by B2C, and I see no trace of it in the logs. Are OIDC `/userinfo` endpoints even supported?

Below is my claims provider section.

```xml
<ClaimsProvider>
  <DisplayName>Provider</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="provider-oidc">
      <DisplayName>Providerprofile</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
      <OutputTokenFormat>JWT</OutputTokenFormat>
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="client_id">preprod-provider</Item>
        <Item Key="scope">openid profile</Item>
        <Item Key="response_types">code</Item>
        <Item Key="METADATA">https://preprod.provider.com/oidc/.well-known/openid-configuration</Item>
        <Item Key="ProviderName">https://preprod.provider.com/oidc</Item>

        <Item Key="state">123abc</Item>
        <Item Key="HttpBinding">POST</Item>

        <Item Key="UsePolicyInRedirectUri">true</Item>
        <Item Key="authorization_endpoint">https://preprod.provider.com/oidc/authorize</Item>
        <Item Key="token_endpoint">https://preprod.provider.com/oidc/token</Item>
        <Item Key="ClaimsEndpoint">https://preprod.provider.com/oidc/userinfo</Item>
        <Item Key="ClaimsEndpointAccessTokenName">oauth2_access_token</Item>
        <Item Key="ClaimsResponseFormat">json</Item>

        <!--Item Key="userinfo_endpoint">https://preprod.provider.com/oidc/userinfo</Item-->
      </Metadata>
      <CryptographicKeys>
        <Key Id="client_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_ProviderClientSecret" />
      </CryptographicKeys>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="socialIdpUserId" PartnerClaimType="sub"/>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="providerAuthentication" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" DefaultValue="provider" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="name" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" PartnerClaimType="given_name" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" PartnerClaimType="family_name" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="testClaim" DefaultValue="testValue" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaimsTransformations>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateRandomUPNUserName"/>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserPrincipalName"/>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateAlternativeSecurityId"/>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateSubjectClaimFromAlternativeSecurityId"/>
      </OutputClaimsTransformations>
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Azure AD B2C does not support the userinfo_endpoint.** You can request this feature in the [Azure AD B2C feedback forum](https://aka.ms/aadb2cuv).

There are two workarounds for this:

- At the **application level** - add code that, after obtaining the id_token, calls out to this `userinfo_endpoint` to obtain those extra claims and add them to the token for the rest of the application to leverage
- At the **B2C custom policy level** - add a [callout to a Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-custom-rest-api-netfw) to retrieve the extra claims and add them in the token. Note that you won't be able to call the userinfo_endpoint, rather you'll need to write an *in-between* service that transforms the call REST call from B2C (which doesn't yet support sending an `Authorization: Bearer X` header) into a call to your userinfo_endpoint or to the underlying user store with the extra claims.

Answer (score 0):

While the `OpenIdConnect` Technical Profile doesn't seem to support a userinfo endpoint, you should be able to use the `OAuth2` Technical Profile together with the `ClaimsEndpoint` to get claims from the userinfo endpoint

Answer (score 0):

The user_info endpoint is now supported in ADB2C. Please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/userinfo-endpoint?pivots=b2c-custom-policy for more information.

Comment: I am very ready to be wrong about this, but it seems to me that this link is about exposing a userinfo endpoint to relying parties. I think the OP was asking about Azure as a relying party fetching userinfo from another provider.

Comment: Yes, link is about exposing userinfo endpoint. Wondering if in 2022 is it possible for relying party to fetch userinfo from another provider and add it to the access token if the idp doesn't provide any claims in the id/access token but provide them on userinfo endpoint?

Comment: Anyone found out if this is possible? Having a hard time finding it in docs or examples